# Sharepoint API: Disable versioning of a document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-rest-api

Is there an endpoint to enable/ disable versioning for a document library? I'm using sharepoint online right btw

Answer (score 0):

You could enbale versioning for the library like this:

```
POST https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')
{
 __metadata:
 {
  type: "SP.List"
 },
 EnableVersioning: true
}
```

Reference: https://www.codesharepoint.com/rest-api/enable-versioning-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api